# Retrieving the type of JSX children

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am facing with a challenge where I have to organize the child components depending on their type.

Let's say we have a parent component named `Modal`, defined as follows;

```
interface IModalProps {
    children: ModalHeader | ModalBody | ModalFooter;
}

function Modal({ children }: IModalProps) { ... }
```

And there are other children components that will be nested inside the parent `Modal` component;

```
function ModalHeader(props) { ... }
function ModalBody(props) { ... }
function ModalFooter(props) { ... }
```

What I want to do is to use these components in my `index.tsx` as follows;

```
<Modal>
    <ModalHeader />
    <div /> { /* Desired error: type 'div' does not exist in type 'ModalHeader | ModalBody | ModalFooter' */ }
    <ModalBody />
    <ModalFooter />
</Modal>
```

So by using the `children` property defined with the `IModalProps` interface, I can access to all of these nested components inside the `Modal` component, after nesting them as above. However, it will just give me the components inside an array, without me knowing what element represent which of the child components. **I want to be able to identify the types of these child components inside my parent component**, so that I can apply specific conditions or layouts by using them. For example, I may want to place the `ModalHeader` component inside a `div` where I apply special conditions and stylings, or I may want to set a specific display order as a layout constraint for all of the child components, by using the information about their types.

Are there any way for me to achieve that, without passing these components as named properties?

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of getting a single `children` prop can't you take three props `modalHeader`, `modalFooter`, `modalBody`?

Comment: Like I said in my question, I want to retrieve that without passing these components as named props. They should be nested inside the parent component and being retrieved with the children props.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare the `type` property of the children's props to the relevant component type, or `type.name` property, in your `Modal` component, something like this:

```
React.Children.forEach(children, child => {
    if (child.type === ModalHeader || child.type.name === ModalHeader.name) {
        console.log('Header Component');
    }
});
```

Note: only one check is necessary (either `type` or `type.name`) depending on the version of the packages you are using.

Comment: What should be the type of the children property to access its field named type

Comment: It is expected to be an array of React Components.

Comment: This is a typescript question, so this answer wouldn't benefit me unless I know the specific type that contains the type field within.

Comment: Your `children` prop in the interface `IModalProps` is not expected to be an array, right?

Comment: So apparently, the type `ReactElement` has a field named type, and it works with your answer. If you edit your answer according to that, to be a compatible answer with Typescript, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: ok, then I think ReactElement also supports a `type` property. Check this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-architecture-8u73pk and the documentation https://reactjs.org/blog/2014/10/14/introducing-react-elements.html